# make autocomplete textbox using tableadapter windows forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, tableadapter

i have this piece of code to autocomplete my search textbox

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        DataTableReader reader=this.customerTableAdapter.GetData().CreateDataReader();
        while(reader.Read()){
            coll.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }

        search.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;
```

is that the best way to perform it? or is there a function to make the autocomplete source the column itself directly?

moreover this code filters only the first name, but when i use this piece of code with gridview it gives me better search abilities so it catches any part of the name

```
private void search_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string outputInfo = "";
        string[] keyWords = search.Text.Split(' ');

        foreach (string word in keyWords)
        {
            if (outputInfo.Length == 0)
            {
                outputInfo = "(Name LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
            }
            else
            {
                outputInfo += " AND (Name LIKE '%" + word + "%')";
            }
        }

        //Applies the filter to the DataView
        myView.RowFilter = outputInfo;
    }
```

suggestions please

Comment: According to me everything is proper..

Comment: what about the keyword search code ? how can i combine it in the autocomplete source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this piece of code do the trick without using loops, it fills one column of the table in string array and then it used as `autoCompleteSource`

```
            DataTable dt = this.data_allDataSet.merchandise;
        //use LINQ method syntax to pull the Title field from a DT into a string array...
        string[] postSource = dt
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Select<System.Data.DataRow, String>(x => x.Field<String>("name"))
                            .ToArray();

        var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        source.AddRange(postSource);
        cat_name.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
        cat_name.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        cat_name.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```